# How do I insert into table1 some values from table 2 and some literal values?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this gets confusing, I am new to MySQL and writing queries.
Essentially, I want to write a stored procedure in MySQL that inserts one row in table1 *for each* value in table2 plus some additional literal values.

For example:

The table "Liked_Movies" has the columns

```
user_name time_of_entry  movie_name  foo
```

and the table "Movies" has the columns

```
movie_name  genre  rating
```

The stored procedure takes in `userName` as a variable.

How would I insert, into "Liked_Movies", one row for every movie_name in "Movies" where genre="action" while also inserting the stored procedure's passed in value `userName` for `user_name`, the result of `NOW()` for `time_of_entry`, and the string `"bar"` for every `foo` column?

Hopefully that makes sense. If I can provide any additional information, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert literal values directly into your `SELECT` for the `INSERT`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Liked_Movies (user_name, time_of_entry, movie_name, foo)
SELECT username, NOW(), m.movie_name, 'foo' FROM movies m
```